# Process Explorer Itself Consuming High CPU

Tags: windows-10, process-explorer

[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) version 16.32 from Sysinternals is consuming almost 100% of 1 core.  I was on Windows 10 version 1909 and upgraded to Windows 10 version 20H2 build 19042.572.  Process Explorer consumes high CPU on both versions.  I am used to seeing around 12% CPU usage of 1 core.  How do I restore the CPU usage of Process Explorer?

I've tried the following:

1. Rebooting the laptop
2. Restarting Process Explorer
3. Removing almost all columns except process name
4. Removing all but 1 icon in task tray
5. Set the update speed from every second to every 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Process Explorer here and have used it lots. 10% or so CPU is normal and what I have here. Newest version of Windows 10 V2004 and also on Windows Insider about the same.

Try the Windows 10 initial repairs and restart after.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

Uninstall Process Explorer

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Now reinstall Process Explorer (64-bit)

As noted, restart and test and see if PE usage returns to normal.

I assume the high CPU is constant. PE takes about a minute to settle down.

Comment: The high CPU is an average after Process Explorer has been running for hours.

Comment: Note: After executing the above steps and starting Process Explorer, it took several minutes before it reduced its CPU usage to 25% of 1 core.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Windows build. I opened ProcMon and it kept making endless child processes. I was watching it go haywire in ProcExp, but that was working ok.

Comment: That is an interesting case.  In my case, both Windows 10 v1909 and v20H2 had the problem.  Process Explorer was not creating child processes.